# Is it possible to replace Markdown footnotes with links using Pandoc?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, youtrack, footnotes

I want to convert a Markdown which uses extended syntax for footnotes to strict Markdown which YouTrack Knowledge Base uses. I want to rewrite footnotes using links syntax.

I wonder if there is already a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution for it yet, but [here is a feature request about that](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-57341/Consider-support-for-footnote-markdown), so please feel free to vote for it.